# Converting keras model to tensorflow lite gives "FailedPreconditionError"

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, tensorflow-lite

I have a model in `keras` using 1 layer of LSTM with bidirectional wrapper, which I want to convert to `tensorflow` lite.

I'm using the callback `ModelCheckpoint` while training the model to save the model and the best weights.

Then I'm using this code to reload the best trained model from the checkpoint:

```
predictor = None
path_Load = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'LSTMB_CheckPoints.hdf5')
predictor = load_model(path_Load)
predictor.load_weights(path_Load)
```

Upon checking with validation data, the model loads succesfully and works as intended. Now I want to convert it to Tensorflow Lite, with a bit of code I found on stackoverflow -

```
keras_file = path_Load
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file(keras_file)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

I thought maybe the checkpoint file was causing problems, so I resaved the model, and called converter again using -

```
keras_file = "keras_model.h5"
tf.keras.models.save_model(predictor, keras_file)
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file(keras_file)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

upon which I am getting this error -

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value bidirectional_1/backward_lstm_1/kernel
     [[{{node _retval_bidirectional_1/backward_lstm_1/kernel_0_0}}]]
```

I tried to run the global variable initializer function of tensorflow

```
predictor = None
path_Load = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'LSTMB_CheckPoints.hdf5')
predictor = load_model(path_Load)
predictor.load_weights(path_Load)
with tf.Session() as sess:
     sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
keras_file = "keras_model.h5"
tf.keras.models.save_model(predictor, keras_file)
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file(keras_file)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

before resaving the model, to check whether the model variables were getting uninitialized, but the error still remains.

has anyone faced a similar issue and found a solution? Is there a way to convert the sequential model to tflite directly without saving and reloading the file?

Comment: The LSTM op is not yet supported in TensorFlow Lite. You can try [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select).

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal I tried using the method like - 

`converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir)
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS,
                                       tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open(target_path, "wb").write(tflite_model)`

but I am getting the error - 
RuntimeError: MetaGraphDef associated with tags {'serve'} could not be found in SavedModel. To inspect available tag-sets in the SavedModel, please use the SavedModel CLI: `saved_model_cli`

Answer (score 0):

**you should save your model in the .pb file.**
First, load you model if you saved it before and then run

```
YOUR_MODEL.save('NAME.pb').
```

Now you have a folder that contains saved model.pb and necessary other files and folders.
Create converter instance:

```
convertor = tensorflow.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model('NAME.pb').
```

At the end convert your model and save it:

```
tfmodel = converter.convert()
open("model.tflite","wb").write(tfmodel)
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to save your model into .h5 format by running

```
model.save("model.h5")
```

afterward, follow those steps

```
new_model= tf.keras.models.load_model(filepath="model.h5")
tflite_converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(new_model)
tflite_model = tflite_converter.convert()
open("tf_lite_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```